# How do I resolve application errors?

Tags: html, css, node.js, heroku

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iEDk.png)

I raised CTFd through heroku, but I keep getting an application error.
I also set up Procfile, but it keeps getting errors.
How can I solve this error?

Comment: What exactly is the application error?

Comment: You should prefer copy-pasting the error instead of posting a screenshot of it.